# JSF1.2 and RichFaces 3.2.1 upgrade

Tags: jsf, upgrade, richfaces, jsf-1.2, jboss-seam

I have the project which is designed and developed on very legacy frameworks. The frameworks which we are currently using are:

- jboss-seam-2.2.1.jar
- jsf-api-1.2_04-p02.jar
- jsf-facelets-1.1.14.jar
- jsf-impl-1.2_04-p02.jar
- richfaces-impl-3.2.1.GA.jar

These are quite old frameworks, may be around 12 years old or more.

Now, we are planning to upgrade these version to the latest stable version of the frameworks.
The question is, can we directly move from jsf1.2 to jsf 2.3 ? I don't see any documentation or reference for this migration.

Along with JSF upgrade what all are the components we may need to upgrade? Any Direction ?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0

Comment: There is no 'latest stable' version of RichFaces. It reached a richly merited end of life in 2016. You will have to redo it all using either JSF 2 native facilities or PrimeFaces to fill in the gaps.